# nginx add header based on sub path

Tags: nginx

I have the following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    ...
    if ($host = "www.domain.tld") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://site.domain.tld";
    }
```

what is the correct way to change the header so that if the path is contains `/api` the header then becomes:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://docs.domain.tld";
```

any advice is much appreciated

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should better create 2 different locations and [share common proxy config and include as-needed](https://serverfault.com/questions/373578/how-can-i-configure-nginx-locations-to-share-common-configuration-options).

**/etc/nginx/proxy.conf**

```
try_files $uri =404;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
...
```

**Your Host Config File**

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    ...
    if ($host = "www.domain.tld") {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://site.domain.tld";
    }
}
location ~ .*/api.*.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    ....
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://docs.domain.tld";
    ....
}
```

Moreover, this can also be solved by using if statement on the $[uri](https://serverfault.com/questions/373578/how-can-i-configure-nginx-locations-to-share-common-configuration-options) variable. But **[If Is Evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)**.
That said you should avoid using if statement on the $host it is a [bad practice](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if).